# best approach for extract / extracting images / image sequence from videos / video file in Java

Tags: java, image, video, ffmpeg, sequence

Well, there is FFMPEG and some Java bindings and wrappers for it but I need to distribute for each specific platform the right binary file of FFMPEG.

Isnt there any plain Java solution or library without any dependencies like FFMPEG for converting a video fle to an image sequence?

Solutions like FFMPEG, XUGGLER or JMF (abandoned) are not suitable. Is there really no pure Java solution for this?

Maybe for specific video codecs / files at least?

I just want to extract the images from the video file to jpeg / png files and save them to the disk

Comment: Since there are so much different encodings available I think ffmpeg is the option you have.

Comment: well but then I need binaries and its not available as pure Java solution

Comment: There is [Jave](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/).

Comment: Jave needs also specificbinaries for each platform, jffmpeg (real java port?) is maybe one solution, but there has to be a better one.

Comment: This Stack Overflow question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114413/java-guide-to-write-a-custom-video-codec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there really no pure Java solution for [extracting images from a video stream]?

Let's see.  You have to:

- Decode the video.
- Present the decoded images at least as fast as 24 images / second.  I suppose you can skip this step.
- Save the decoded images.

It appears that decoding the video would be the most challenging step.  People and companies have spent years developing codecs (encoder / decoder) for various video formats.

There's a project on SourceForge, [JMF wrapper for ffmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jffmpeg/), that has developed a few pure Java video codecs.  Perhaps you can look at their source code and see how to develop a Java video codec for yourself.

You can look for other pure Java video codecs if you wish.

Comment: is there some specific codec which would suit best? mjpeg? any ffmpeg wrapper can not be used.

Comment: @Daniel Ruf:  The one that accurately decodes your video?  You need a video codec for every video encoding that you want to process.  As I said in my answer, the wrapper project produced some pure Java video codecs.  Those pure Java video codecs are what you want.

Comment: I want to choose the best encoding for the first small version and thought about Motion JPEG. But it seems it is not standardized.

Comment: @Daniel Ruf: Take your pick of the formats listed here: http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/formats.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure Java implementation of the following codecs: H.264 ( AVC ), MPEG 1/2, Apple ProRes, JPEG; and the following file formats: MP4 ( ISO BMF, QuickTime ), Matroska, MPEG PS and MPEG TS.
The library is called JCodec ( http://www.jcodec.org ).
It has very little documentation for now but the development team is constantly working on this.
Here's how you can simply grab a frame from an MP4 file ( sample from their web site ):

```
int frameNumber = 150;
BufferedImage frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("filename.mp4"), frameNumber);
ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));
```

To add JCodec to your project you can simply add below to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For **latest** version, see [here](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec#getting-started).

Comment: well, they failed at creating the website, www.jcodec.org does not work but jcodec.org (without www), sad that they have not a real documentation for the methods, classes ... =(

Comment: I tried their sample, but I get NullPointerException and don't know why. Could someone help please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344051/nullpointerexception-in-framegrab-getframe

Comment: I would suggest to NOT use jcodec if you need a fast solution. The last version 0.1.10 takes +- 700 ms to grab one frame. It's certainly not suitable for video playback

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;

public class Read{

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, Exception, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("C:/Users/Digilog/Downloads/Test.mp4");
        frameGrabber.start();
        IplImage i;
        try {
            for(int ii=0;ii<frameGrabber.getLengthInFrames();ii++){

            i = frameGrabber.grab();
            BufferedImage  bi = i.getBufferedImage();
            String path = "D:/Image/Image"+ii+".png";
            ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File(path));

            }
            frameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This will generate all the video frames that the mp4 video has !

Comment: doesn't this depend on OpenCV and some other binaries and libraries?