# NullPointerException in FrameGrab.getFrame

Tags: java, video, video-capture

I would like to get frame from video using [jcodec](http://jcodec.org/), but I get NullPointerException.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab;
import org.jcodec.api.JCodecException;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int frameNumber = 150;  

        try {
            BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            try {
                frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("/Users/AG/Downloads/video.mp4"), frameNumber);
            } catch (JCodecException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.deblock.DeblockingFilter.calcBsH(DeblockingFilter.java:167)
at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.deblock.DeblockingFilter.deblockFrame(DeblockingFilter.java:80)
at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder$FrameDecoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:101)
at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:61)
at org.jcodec.api.specific.AVCMP4Adaptor.decodeFrame(AVCMP4Adaptor.java:40)
at org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab.decodeLeadingFrames(FrameGrab.java:184)
at org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab.seekToFramePrecise(FrameGrab.java:111)
at org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab.getFrame(FrameGrab.java:331)
at com.mycompany.video_extractor.App.main(App.java:27)
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception, and what diagnostics have you performed? Note that if you get a `JCodecException`, `frame` won't be assigned a new value - but you're calling `ImageIO.write` anyway...

Comment: I get exception on line frame = FrameGrab.getFrame line. I did no diagnostic only checked FrameGrab class and found compiled code..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your stacktrace, but this line.-

```
ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));
```

may be throwing the `Exception` it `frame` happens to be `null`. I'd rewrite the code like this.-

```
try {
    BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("/Users/AG/Downloads/video.mp4"), frameNumber);
    if (frame != null) {
        ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));
    } 

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (JCodecException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Notice that there's no sense in instantiating a `new BufferedImage` if you're reassigning it in the next line, and there's no sense in running the third line (`ImageIO.write`) if `FrameGrab.getFrame` returns `null` (which is most probably what's happening here).